# How do I fade out an element 5 seconds after it's created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element, `.toast`, created by a function which prints `EVENT_weather_Sunny`.

```
var EVENT_weather_Sunny = "<div class='toast' onclick='jQuery(this).fadeOut()' onload='jQuery(this).delay(5000).fadeOut()'><div class='toastIcon'><img src='weather_sunny-icon.png'></div><div class='toastLabel'><h1>Weather: Sunny</h1><p>Today's weather forecast predicts sunshine.<p>Click to close.</div></div>";
```

How do I make `.toast` fade out after 5 seconds of it existing?

Edit: I have tried the following suggestion but it hasn't worked so far.

```
function toast(html) {
    $("#toast").prepend(html);
    jQuery(html).delay(5000).fadeOut();
}
```

I use the variable `html` as there are multiple instances of `.toast` to be created, with different names like `EVENT_weather_Sunny`, `EVENT_incident_Fire`.

Comment: Use setTimeout.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you for responding! I tried that but it didn't work. I can't figure out how to get setTimeout to work specifically for the element that it's in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` element not have `onload` event. just call `jQuery(EVENT_weather_Sunny).delay(5000).fadeOut()` when you add it to the html

```js
var EVENT_weather_Sunny = "<div class='toast' onclick='jQuery(this).fadeOut()'><div class='toastIcon'><img src='weather_sunny-icon.png'></div><div class='toastLabel'><h1>Weather: Sunny</h1><p>Today's weather forecast predicts sunshine.<p>Click to close.</div></div>";

toast(EVENT_weather_Sunny);

function toast(html) {
    html = jQuery(html);
    $("#toast").prepend(html);
    html.delay(5000).fadeOut();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toast"></div>
```

Comment: Tukachinksy Thank you for responding! That doesn't work for my code for some reason. I need a way to trigger the div's fadeOut within the div. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: you cannot do it within a div. can you share snipped of your code where you trying to call it outside and it's don't work? it's should do..

Comment: I have added it to the original post

Comment: I think i found the problem. since the variable is only the string, any time you wrap it in jQuery you create a new element, and not refer to the old one. try to make the `EVENT_weather_Sunny` to be a jQuery object, then refer to it every time

Comment: start with `html = $(html);` then use it, instead wrap it every time with `jQuery()` and create a new object

Comment: I updated my snipped for your snipped. as you can see, just turn the html into jQuery object before working with it

Answer (score 0):

fadeOut itself take time as param.

> $(selector).fadeOut(speed,easing,callback)